# Copy an on premise Windows folder to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I have an old archive folder that exists on an on premise Windows server that I need to put into an S3 bucket, but having issues, it's more my knowledge of AWS tbh, but I'm trying.

I have created the S3 bucket and I can to attach it to the server using net share (AWS gives you the command via the AWS gateway) and I gave it a drive letter. I then tried to use robocopy to copy the data, but it didn't like the drive letter for some reason.

I then read I can use the AWS CLI so I tried something like:

```
aws s3 sync z: s3://archives-folder1
```

I get - fatal error: Unable to locate credentials

I guess I need to put some credentials in somewhere (.aws), but after reading too many documents I'm not sure what to do at this point, could someone advise?

Maybe there is a better way.

Thanks

Comment: You need to setup credentials https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to 'attach' the S3 bucket to your system. You can simply use the AWS CLI command to communicate directly with Amazon S3.

First, however, you need to provide the AWS CLI with a set of AWS credentials that can be used to access the bucket. You can do this with:

```
aws configure
```

It will ask for an **Access Key** and **Secret Key**. You can obtain these from the Security Credentials tab when viewing your IAM User in the IAM management console.